# puxando de um formulario para uma tabela

Tags: formulário, tabela-html

Tenho um formulário onde quero escrever aqueles dados la e inserir ele em uma tabela

```html
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">DATA DO AGENDAMENTO:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name"  " >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">CAPTADOR:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
        <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">EQUIPE:</label>
        <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
            <option selected>EQUIPE </option>
            <option value="1">EQUIPE 1</option>
            <option value="2">EQUIPE 2</option>
            <option value="3">EQUIPE 3</option>
            <option value="3">EQUIPE 4</option>
        </select>
</form>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">CLIENTE:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name"  >
</div>
<DIV class="form-group">
    <label>Profissao </label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" class ="form-control"id="nome" placeholder="Pesquisar pelo nome">
</DIV>  
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">EMPREENDIMENTO:</label>
    <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
          <option selected>BOTUCATU</option>
          <option value="1">IBIS 1</option>
          <option value="2">IBIS 2</option>
          <option value="3">IBIS 3</option>
          <option value="3">IBIS 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br/>
<label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">HORARIO DO AGENDAMENTO:</label>
<select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
    <option value="08:00">08:00</option> 
    <option value="08:30">08:30</option> 
    <option value="09:00">09:00</option> 
    <option value="09:30">09:30</option> 
    <option value="10:00">10:00</option> 
    <option value="10:30">10:30</option> 
    <option value="11:00">11:00</option> 
    <option value="11:30">11:30</option> 
    <option value="12:00">12:00</option> 
    <option value="12:30">12:30</option> 
    <option value="13:00">13:00</option> 
    <option value="13:30">13:30</option> 
    <option value="14:00">14:00</option> 
    <option value="15:00">15:00</option> 
    <option value="15:30">15:30</option> 
    <option value="16:00">16:00</option> 
    <option value="16:30">16:30</option> 
    <option value="17:00">17:00</option> 
    <option value="17:30">17:30</option> 
    <option value="18:00">18:00</option> 
    <option value="18:30">18:30</option> 
    <option value="19:00">19:00</option> 
    <option value="19:30">19:30</option> 
    <option value="20:00">20:00</option> 
</select>
<br/>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="my-1 mr-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">STATUS:</label>
    <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelectPref">
        <option selected>NAO COMPARECEU</option>
        <option value="1"> DESMARCOU</option>
        <option value="2">CONFIRMADO</option>
        <option value="3">COMPARECEU</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">DIA QUE AGENDOU:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name"  >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">TELEFONE DO CLINETE:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control  ">
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  " data-dismiss="modal">Agendar</button>
</form>
```